# what is SQL query for getting Sonarqube Lines of Code data

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

My problem is about getting data from Sonar database. I want to get lines of code data for specific projects or group. Basicly I need a query for get LoC data from database. For example, at dashboard I've some information about this. I need sonar get this info by using which sql query? I send a pic to my dashboard. Maybe you can get some thing from there.[i want to get these data or sum them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chk1S.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

The database is not an API. In the long run you will be happier if you treat it like a black box, and use [web services](https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/measures/component) instead to retrieve your data.

Comment: in metric table there is "ncloc" parameter, i need by using this parameter get loc of specific projects. i try to code desktop application see some different dashboards.